# MVC Display Binary Image from ViewBag

Tags: image, model-view-controller, binary

I am having problem when displaying the binary image in MVC view. I stored images in database as binary format and then assigned to ViewBag in Controller. How do I assign viewbag data to image in View?

Controller

```
            ItemBO mibo = new ItemBO();
            ViewBag.Picture1 = Convert.ToByte(mibo.GetImage(1));
```

View

```
           var elem = document.createElement("img");     
           elem.setAttribute("src", @ViewBag.Picture1);

           elem.setAttribute("style", "height:100%");
           elem.setAttribute("alt", "Image");

           document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(elem);
```

Above code doesn't work as I expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try following,

```
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ViewBag.Picture1);
     string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
     <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" />
```